# PHP preg_replace $1 without space

Tags: php, preg-replace, space

I have a problem with preg_replace and $1 + variable without a space between $1 and the variable.

I have this code:

```
$replace_id = 5000;
$search = 1000;
$movies = '[1000,2000,2300,1234]';
$new_movies = preg_replace('#(,|\[)'.$search.'(,|\])#Uis','$1'.$replace_id.'$2',$movies);
echo $new_movies;
```

The output:

```
000,2000,2300,1234]
```

But I want to have this output:

```
[5000,2000,2300,1234]
```

When I use the preg_replace with a space between $1 and $replace_id:

```
   $new_movies = preg_replace('#(,|\[)'.$search.'(,|\])#Uis','$1 '.$replace_id.'$2',$movies);
```

It works perfect, but I need this without a space inside!

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: your second code is identical to the first, but am I right in thinking that you're trying to replace with a pattern like `$15000` where `$1` is the token and `5000` is a text literal?

Comment: Oh sorry I added the space now ;) Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: OK, in that case my answer should help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

> When working with a replacement pattern where a backreference is immediately followed by another number (i.e.: placing a literal number immediately after a matched pattern), you cannot use the familiar \1 notation for your backreference. \11, for example, would confuse preg_replace() since it does not know whether you want the \1 backreference followed by a literal 1, or the \11 backreference followed by nothing. In this case the solution is to use \${1}1. This creates an isolated $1 backreference, leaving the 1 as a literal.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

So I would use `'${1}'.$replace_id`

Comment: Thanks! Actually it is not '\${1}'.$replace_id but '${1}'.$replace_id (without the slash)

Comment: @Wikunia ah ok. I was wondering. Unfortunately the documentation is rarely clear about whether it's using `''` or `""` quotes… Anyway, fixed.